# How to select all records from a 2-columns table as a single JSON object?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-json

I have prepared a [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/0) for my question.

In PostgreSQL 15 I have a table of English words.

Some of them have an explanation/description and some not:

```
create table words (word text not null, explanation text);

insert into words (word, explanation) values
    ( 'AAHED' , null ),
    ( 'AAH' , 'To exclaim in delight' ),
    ( 'AAL' , 'East Indian shrub' ),
    ( 'AARDVARK' , null );
```

I would like to select them as the following JSON object (and dump to a JSON file at my web server, for later inclusion in a Javascript app):

```
{
  "AAHED" : "",
  "AAH" : "To exclaim in delight",
  "AAL" : 'East Indian shrub",
  "AARDVARK" : ""
}
```

So I have tried the following queries, but cannot get the desired result yet:

```
select json_build_object(word, explanation) from words;

with cte as (select word, explanation from words) select row_to_json(c) from cte c;
```

What would be the suitable [JSON function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-json.html) here please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `json_object_agg()`, because you need an aggregation of records:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3AJOgG7-)

```
SELECT
    json_object_agg(word, explanation) 
FROM words;
```

Comment: Thank you, I will put `psql my_database -t -c "SELECT JSON_OBJECT_AGG(word, COALESCE(explanation, '')) FROM words;" > /var/www/html/english_words.json` into my cronjob

Comment: In my real application I actually have 2 tables: words_nouns and words_verbs (with no explanation column). When I try to UNION them by the following query: `SELECT JSON_OBJECT_AGG(word, COALESCE(explanation, '')) FROM words_nouns UNION SELECT JSON_OBJECT_AGG(word, '') FROM words_verbs;` then unfortunately I get the strange `ERROR:  42883: could not identify an equality operator for type json`

Comment: Fixed my problem with 2 tables by using: `WITH cte AS (SELECT word, COALESCE(explanation, '') AS explanation FROM words_nouns UNION SELECT word, '' AS explanation FROM words_verbs) SELECT JSON_OBJECT_AGG(hashed, explanation) FROM cte;`